# How should I write IAM to make only a certain VPC can send mail via SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ses, redash

I use Redash on EC2 instance, and I have to send invitation mails via Amazon SES.
I'd like to add a setting to restrict mail sender to inside a certain VPC where the Redash instance is located.

Here's my IAM for SES:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ses:SendRawEmail",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpce": "vpce-******"
                },
                "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                    "ses:Recipients": "*@mycompany.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But I can't send any mail. I think it's because I use VPC endpoint in the code above. It's not available for SES yet.
Is there any other way to specify a certain VPC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting challenge!

The Amazon SES interface is on the internet, so theoretically anything can access it. Normally, policy restrictions use **permissions on the IAM User or Role** that calls SES to determine whether calls are allowed, rather than from where the call is made.

I assume you are doing this because you only want your Production system to send emails, rather than Dev/Test systems.

However, it is *not* possible to restrict via VPC, because Amazon SES has no visibility to the concept of a VPC. It simply receives API calls via the Internet.

If your application is in a private subnet and **sends requests via NAT Gateway**, then you could add a policy to restrict based upon the IP address of the NAT Gateway.

You could do this either by putting the restriction on the `Allow` statement, or by adding a `Deny` statement.

See: [AWS: Denies Access to AWS Based on the Source IP - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_deny-ip.html)